Pyinstrument ProfilerState object is not callable
I am working on using PyInstrument to profile FastAPI requests. When I am trying to make this post call:
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/model/lumalee/decisions/result/file/?shap_values=0&libsvm=0' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@clean_sample'

The task is getting stuck, and when I refresh the web page, I am getting this error:
 asctime=2024-04-16 15:11:20,897, level=ERROR [uvicorn.error] msg=Exception in ASGI application
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 108, in __call__
     response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
   File "/home/dsci/classifier-api/app/core/middleware.py", line 25, in profile_request
     await call_next(request)
   File "src/memray/_memray.pyx", line 712, in memray._memray.Tracker.__exit__
   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 58, in setprofile
     def setprofile(func):
 TypeError: 'pyinstrument.stat_profile.ProfilerState' object is not callable

Basically, the error is happening here:
def register_profiler(app: FastAPI):
    @app.middleware("http")
    async def profile_request(request: Request, call_next):
        """
            Profile the CPU and memory of the current request
        """
        if config.PROFILING_ENABLED is True:
            memray_file_path = memray.FileDestination('/tmp/output.bin', overwrite=True)
            with memray.Tracker(destination=memray_file_path, trace_python_allocators=True):
                await call_next(request) <----------------------------------------HERE THE ERROR OCCURS
            subprocess.run(
                ["memray", "summary", "/tmp/output.bin"]
            )

            profiler = Profiler(interval=0.001, async_mode="enabled")
            profiler.start()
            response = await call_next(request)
            profiler.stop()
            profiler.print(show_all=True)
            return response
        return await call_next(request)

Any idea why I am getting not callable error? Due to this error, we won't be able to profile post calls in FastAPI which is a roadblock for us. Please help in resolving this issue. Thanks.
